# Know when row color changed + WPF + DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Quick question.

I have a DataGrid that get's updated automatically through a SQL-Dependency.
and I have a trigger set up to change the BackgroundProperty to a color based on a few values (either red or green).
I really was hoping of using an eventsetter with my trigger.

My question is: Which eventhandler fires, when the trigger changes the background? Ive tried DependencyPropertyDescriptor - which works when checking itemssource changed, but NOT DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty or Control.BackgroundProperty (just doesn't fire)
with my dependencyproperty like

```
var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(Control)); 
desc.AddValueChanged(MyDataGrid,MyEventHandler);
```

with my event like this:

```
            DataGrid mygrid = sender as DataGrid;
            var itemsSource = mygrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
            if (null != itemsSource)
            {           
               foreach (var item in itemsSource)
                {
                    var row = mygrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                    if (null != row)
                    {
                        if (Equals(Brushes.Red, row.Background))
                        {
                        //Do whatever
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

but row is always null - why is this?.
EDIT: it returns null because it is virtualized and is not "in view".

I was hoping to be able to create an eventhandler to go with an eventsetter in my datatrigger

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely your `Trigger` changes the `Background` colour dependent on some data value, doesn't it? Why don't you just monitor the relevant data property instead?

Comment: Well, here's the thing - the trigger value, is dynamic (with (valueconverters)), based on another sqltable

Comment: But surely at some stage, it depends on the new data coming in... you just said it's based on another SQL table. Can you not iterate the incoming data to find whatever triggers the `Trigger` and act on it at that stage?

Answer (score 1):

what  @Sheridan is suggesting is that you already know when the background color should be changed so just use that data and do the extra work you wanted,
but if you simply must create a callback to Background changes then you can use [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx) to add changed handlers:

var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Control.BackGroundProperty, typeof(Control));
desc.AddValueChanged(this,yourEventHandler);

Comment: @AlekCarlsen what do you get? it doesn't matter if DataGridRow or TextBox... 
post what you've tried

Comment: Well i can get it to fire on itemssource changed, but NOT when I use ..DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Control.BackgroundProperty.. it does not fire when background is changed

Comment: @AlekCarlsen show the code that does and the one that doesnt work